# AngularJS: filter in controller on all field except one field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs app i get via json such example of data:

```
{"id":"1a", "name": "aaa", "emails": {{"123@123.com"}, {"123@123.info"}}},
{"id":"2a", "name": "aba", "emails": {{"23@123.com"}, {"3@123.info"}}},
{"id":"3a", "name": "aab", "emails": {{"3@123.com"}, {"3@123.info"}}},
```

and for performance reasons i didn't use filter for ng-repeat, but use ng-show schema...

so in controller i have such code (search is my inputs value):

```
  $scope.$watch('search', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.filteredArray = $filter('filter')($scope.users, $scope.search, newVal);
  });
```

but it search even in id's, for example i enter a and get it from id, but i do not need field id here...

So how to search with filter only in specific fields?

Comment: You say you dont use `filter` in `ng-repeat` for performance reasons, but then you are using `filter` inside the controller. Thats literally the exact same thing; there is no performance change.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg performace change is huge man! For example filter in ng-repeat modify dom, and when you have 1000 items it's visible. When you use something like: `ng-show="([user] | filter:search).length > 0;"` on ng-repeat `ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:predicate:reverse"` dom is not modified, only it's visibility is modified

Comment: @brabertaser1992 `ng-show` also modifies DOM (by adding and removing `ng-hide` class) to make element invisible. Filters slow-down application because they trigger digest cycle at least twice for every single change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you care about performance, probably the best choice would be not to use `$filter('filter')` at all. Assuming your data is a JSON you can do the following:

```js
function contains(src, value, except) {
  var key;
  switch(typeof src) {
    case 'string':
    case 'number':
    case 'boolean':
      return String(src).indexOf(value) > -1;
    case 'object':
      except = except || [];
      for(key in src) {
        if( src.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
            except.indexOf(key) < 0 &&
            contains(src[key], value, except)
        ) {
          return true;
        }
      }
  }
  return false;
}

angular.module('app', []).
  factory('appService', function() {
    var data = [
      {"id":"1a", "name": "aaa", "emails": ["123@123.com", "123@123.info"]},
      {"id":"2a", "name": "aba", "emails": ["23@123.com", "3@123.info"]},
      {"id":"3a", "name": "aab", "emails": ["3@123.com", "3@123.info", ["1@123.com", "2@123.info"]]}
    ];
    return {
      getFilteredData: function(filter, except) {
        return filter ? data.filter(function(item) {
          return contains(item, filter, except)
        }) : data.slice(0);
      }
    }
  }).
  controller('appController', ['$scope', 'appService', function($scope, appService) {
    $scope.search = '';
    $scope.$watch('search', function(val) {
      $scope.data = appService.getFilteredData(val, ['id']);
    });
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <input ng-model="search" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }"/>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{::item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Code above will make a deep search in all fields of data and it's items excluding list of fields passed as parameter (in this example `['id']`)

Tip #1: Implementing business logic inside controller is kind of bad practice in Angular, which has services for that purpose.

Tip #2: If you have large data-sets to be displayed, [debouncing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) filter change will be very beneficial from performance point of view.

Tip #3: If your data-set items are immutable, you can take advantage of [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) (using `{{::item}}` syntax) and speed-up your app by reducing number of watches created by Angular.

Comment: what would be if emails containt subArray?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 nested arrays will work as well. I updated example, now the third item contains nested arrays of emails. It works for any number of nesting levels of arrays and objects since `contains` function is recursive

Comment: pastebin.com/VjuXPVWY - here is my json. Didn't work.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Your JSON seems to have invalid whitespace characters at the beginning of each line, which made the whole JSON invalid. After removing them, works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/caNHFCjRVoHEeM5V81mR?p=preview

Comment: your solution reCreate dom objects. This is a little bit to bad affect on performance

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I've checked: all possible DOM elements are re-used and not re-created once you type in filter. How to check: 1. run example from answer; 2. open development tools, save reference to second li; 3. type in filter aba; see that only the second li is presented; 4. find that li and check that it equals your saved reference :)

Answer (score 2):

> Several answers have been given already, and great tips were given. My contribution will not summarise the work of others, but just mention an  alternate way to filter data with angularjs, with performance in mind: **using an extremely fast, third-party filtering tool**.

---

Yes, having filters in the ng-repeat with `x in data | myFilter` is great for readability, but performs poorly with a large collection, as the filter is evaluated repeatedly.

With large collections, it is best to trade readability for performance, and filter in the controller, like mentioned in the OP.

---

Now if you are going to filter in the controller for performance's sake, you might as well not re-invent the wheel, and use existing filtering tools.

Here is a plunker with a simple toolbox, **filtering instantly** a collection of a **half-million** documents.

*I wrote it several months ago, as the filtering of a collection of 3000+ documents was slowing down my app when I used either custom or built-in angularjs filters.*

[filter a large collection using an extremely fast third-party tool: **crossFilter**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6GGQs2?p=preview)

Now enter a number in the box:  the filtering is (almost) instant. In fact, the reason it is not instant is because I introduced a 750ms delay on purpose, to give time to the user to type, and not filter at every key press:
`var filterTextTimeout=750;`

*EDIT: as rightly mentioned in the comments, with angularjs versions >1.2, the `debounce` option of `ng-model` should be used instead of `$timeout`*

---

The filtering tool used is [crossFilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter), along with [ng-crossfilter](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ngCrossfilter).

The reason it can be so fast is that it creates (very quickly) its own sorted indexes.

It comes up with [many features](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference), like RegExp, InArray Filter, fuzzy filters, map-reduce, etc...

Comment: thank you... just that now angularjs has debounce, without need in timeout

Comment: you are right. I originally wrote the code for an angularjs 1.2 app

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the filter [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) by calling filter function on each field you are interested in.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "$filter", function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.users = [{
        "id": "1a",
            "name": "aaa",
            "emails": ["123@123.com", "123@123.info"]
    }, {
        "id": "2a",
            "name": "aba",
            "emails": ["23@123.com", "3@123.info"]
    }, {
        "id": "3a",
            "name": "aab",
            "emails": ["3@123.com", "3@123.info"]
    }];

    $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        //use function to implement a specific expression
        var expression = function (value, index) {
            fields = ['name', 'emails'];
            for (var i in fields) {
                field = fields[i];
                query = {}; //create an expression
                query[field] = $scope.search;
                r = $filter('filter')([value], query);
                if (r.length > 0) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        $scope.filteredArray = $filter('filter')($scope.users, expression)
    });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">Search:
        <input type="text" ng-model="search">
        <div ng-repeat="x in filteredArray">{{x}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also what would be if emails containt subArray?

Comment: when i enter 3@123.info i see nothing, and for other emails too

Comment: @brabertaser1992 It lists all 3 items in my browser. There is no problem at all. Don't tell me you are on IE 8 or earlier...

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Same version but no issue.

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Case sensitive. You need to use `Emails` and `Name` etc.

Comment: Sure thst i renamed it to upprrcase. But didn.t work for me, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your field name to something starting with $, then Angular will skip this field in filtering. Compare https://next.plnkr.co/edit/TjSdGICBfcR8WDyV with original example from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter. I added $ to `name` and now `| filter` skips field `$name` in global filtering using `search.$`.

Answer (score -1):

The comparator for the filter can be an object that mirrors the objects in your array. If this is the case, it will only filter based on the exiting properties. That is to say if `newVal` is an object of the following form:

```
{
  name: someVal,
  emails: otherVal
}
```

You will only filter on `name` and `emails`, not `id`. Having an `id` field which is blank is also fine (that just means you wont search by `id`).

Here is an example:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "$filter", function($scope, $filter){
  $scope.data = [
    {"id":"1a", "name": "aaa", "emails": ["123@123.com", "123@123.info"]},
    {"id":"2a", "name": "aba", "emails": ["23@123.com", "3@123.info"]},
    {"id":"3a", "name": "aab", "emails": ["3@123.com", "3@123.info"]}
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" ng-model="filter.emails">
    <div ng-repeat="x in data | filter:filter">
      {{x}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note how entering a value in the emails input will search the array properly. if you want you can also set both inputs to the same model, and then set that model to `filter.name` and `filter.email`.

```
//html
Search Query: <input type="text" ng-model="query">
//js
$scope.$watch('query', function(newVal, oldVal){
    $scope.filter.name=newVal;
    $scope.filter.emails=newVal;
}
```

Comment: but what would be if i need to find 'a' in name OR email ?

Comment: also what would be if emails containt subArray?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 You can take it out in your own code... I'm just keeping it short for simplicities sake. The main idea is not filter inside or outside the  `ng-repeat`, its that you can filter on an object.

Comment: so you didn't know how with one model for search (i mean input) filter all except one in controller?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I already said that in my answer, on the last line. I guess Ill make a clearer example for you..

Comment: Updated answer with simple example of how to search both with a single input

Comment: `$scope.$watch('search', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
        $scope.filter.FirstName = newVal;
        $scope.filter.Emails.main = newVal;
        $scope.filteredArray = $filter('filter')($scope.users, $scope.search, newVal);
      });`

didn't work